# Proving the equality of a sum and integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, periodic-functions

Taken from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis text: Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^1$ with period $1$. Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N f(n\alpha) = \int_0^1f(t)dt$ for every irrational real number $\alpha$.

A hint also given is to do it first for $f(t)=\exp(2\pi i k t)$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I tried doing this for the function given in the hint, but I end up with $1=0$ in the end (since $\exp(2\pi ik)=1$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, correct?) Anyway, I'm looking for insight as to why I may be getting incorrect answers in my calculations for this hint and also as to how this hint is to help in the solving of the original problem (because I can't seem to make a connection between the two). Thanks in advance!

Comment: For $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, indeed $\exp (2\pi ik) = 1$. But that doesn't mean $\exp(2\pi i kn\alpha) = 1$.

Comment: But isn't $\exp(2\pi ikn\alpha)=\exp(2\pi ikn)^\alpha$ for $k,n\in\mathbb{Z}$? Or am I completely screwing up my fundamentals of complex analysis (which very well could be the case...)

Comment: You use the exponential function to define powers with non-integer exponents (well, for rational exponents, you could do it otherwise, but it's easier to just use $\exp$), $z^\beta = \exp (\beta\cdot (\log z))$ for a branch of the logarithm. It turns out that when you use the appropriate logarithm of $\exp (2\pi i kn)$, then you have $\exp (2\pi ikn\alpha) = \exp(2\pi ikn)^\alpha$, but $\exp(2\pi ikn\alpha)$ is the fundamental thing.

Comment: However, $\exp (2\pi i kn\alpha) = \exp(2\pi i\alpha)^{kn} = \exp(2\pi ik\alpha)^n$ holds, and powers with integer exponents are easily defined without using $\exp$.

Answer (score 1):

the integral is zero for the reason you mention. with $\xi=\exp(2\pi ik\alpha)$ the average on the left evaluates to
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}(\xi^N-1)\frac{\xi}{N(\xi-1)} = 0
$$
in fact since for irrational $\alpha$ the values of $f(n\alpha)$ are asymptotically evenly distributed around the circumference of a circle, their mean, in the limit, must be the centre of the circle

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For some reason I failed to realize that $|\exp(2\pi ik\alpha)|=1$, but I remember that now so I'm good with showing this holds for the hint function. Do you have any suggestions/hints as to how I am supposed to use this information to prove the main part of the problem? I know that as $N\to\infty$ that $\mod(n\alpha,1)$ will become dense in $[0,1]$, but I don't know if that even helps me at all.

Comment: well we need more than density! this seems to belong in the realms of ergodic theory. it would require to show that if $\{a_n\}$ are the fractional parts of $\{n\alpha\}$ then for any interval $I \subset [0,1]$ we have $\lim_{N \to \infty} N^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^N \chi_I(a_n) = m(I)$

Comment: @PiTheMathemagician For the main part, use the (Stone-)Weierstraß approximation theorem.