# Proving $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nf(i)}{n}=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(t)dt$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is $2\pi$-periodic and continuous.
How to prove that
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nf(i)}{n}=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} 
f(t)dt$?

I tried using Weierstrass approximation theorem for $f$, since it is continuous and periodic, but that approach failed.

Comment: Are you familiar with the theory of Fourier series? You an approximate $f$ uniformly by trigonometric polynomials and the result is easy to verify for trigonometric polynomials.

Comment: I have just started learning it, so I don't know too much. Can You give me more details or point me in the right direction. 
Why can I approximate $f$ by trigonometric polynomials?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r%27s_theorem

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/964072/721644) is kind of related.

Comment: And maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/985323/721644).

Comment: Do you know the Stone-Weierstrass theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to show, that an arbitrary trygonometric polynomial $g(x)=a_0+ \sum\limits_{l=1}^{m} a_l\cos(lx)+b_l\sin(lx)$ satisfies
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^n g(k) = \frac1{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}g(t)dt=a_0$$
First, we will show this for the left-hand side.

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^n g(k)&= \frac1{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^n (a_0+\sum\limits_{l=1}^{m} a_l\cos(lk)+b_l\sin(lk)\big) \\
&=\frac1{n}\cdot n \cdot a_0 +\frac1{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \sum\limits_{l=1}^{m} a_l\cos(lk)+b_l\sin(lk)\\\tag{interchanging sums}
&=a_0+\frac1{n}\sum\limits_{l=1}^{m} \sum \limits_{k=1}^n a_l\cos(lk)+b_l\sin(lk)\\
&=a_0+\frac1{n}\sum\limits_{l=1}^{m} a_l\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\cos {(n+\frac{1}{2})l}}{2\sin(\frac{l}{2})} \bigg)  +b_l\bigg(\frac{\cos\frac{l}{2}-\cos{(n+\frac1{2})l}}{2\sin{\frac{l}{2}}} \bigg)
,
\end{align*}
because $$sin(x)+sin(2x)+\dots+sin(nx)=\frac{cos(\frac{x}{2})-cos(nx+\frac{x}{2})}{2sin(\frac{x}{2})}$$
$$cos(x)+cos(2x)+\cdots+ cos(nx)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\cos {(n+\frac{1}{2})x}}{2\sin(\frac{x}{2})}$$
Since every term is bounded independently of $n$ and there are finitely many terms, we have $$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\frac1{n}\left( \sum\limits_{l=1}^{m} a_l\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\cos {(n+\frac{1}{2})l}}{2\sin(\frac{l}{2})} \bigg)  +b_l\bigg(\frac{\cos\frac{l}{2}-\cos{(n+\frac1{2})l}}{2\sin{\frac{l}{2}}} \bigg)\right) =0$$
Right-hand side is easier.
For $n>0$ we have $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos(nx)dx=0$ and $\int_{0}^{2\pi}sin(nx)=0$, which implies that
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}g(t)dt=a_0$$
Let $G_m$ be a sequence of trigonometric polynomial, such that $G_m(x)\rightrightarrows f(x)$.
By Fejér's theorem  is such a sequence, because sequence of partial sums of Fourier series meets the criteria. We will show that

$$\lim \limits_{m\to \infty}\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^n G_m(k)=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\lim \limits_{m \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^n G_m(k)=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^n f(k)$$
By uniform convergence of $G_m$, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $M\in \mathbb{N}$, such that for $m>M$, we have $|G_m(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. Thus
$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^n G_m(k)-f(k)\right|\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^n |G_m(k)-f(k)|\leq \frac{1}{n}\cdot n\cdot \epsilon=\epsilon $$
Since this limit is independent of $n$ we get desired equalities.

By uniform convergence of $G_m$, we can move the limit inside the integral
$$\lim \limits_{m\to \infty} \int_0^{2\pi}G_m(t)dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\lim \limits_{m\to \infty}G_m(t)dt=\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)dt$$
Finally, using the result obtained for trygonometric polynomials, we conclude:
$$ \frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)dt=\lim \limits_{m\to\infty}\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}G_m(t)dt=\lim \limits_{m\to \infty}\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^n G_m(k)$$
Which means that
$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)dt=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^n f(k) $$